# Hide <div> element when all child <div> values are all zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML that is dynamically generated. The number of "points__fees__value__item" div is variable.

```
<div class="points__fees">
    <div class="points__fees__label">Fees / Charges</div>
    <div class="points__fees__value">
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="star$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">63,000</span> Star $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="63000" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="diamond$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">50,000</span> Diamond $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="50000" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="gold$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Gold $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML is part of a larger HTML form. Depending on the user's inputs, the values of the "points__fees__text" span and input "value" attribute will change accordingly using jQuery and JavaScript. So far all these are working properly.

There is a requirement such that if all the values in the "value" attribute of all the input elements are all 0, the entire "points__fees" div should be hidden. In other words, when the following scenario occurs, the entire "points__fees" div should be hidden. How do I use jQuery or just JavaScript to do this checking?

```
<div class="points__fees">
    <div class="points__fees__label">Fees / Charges</div>
    <div class="points__fees__value">
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="star$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Star $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="diamond$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Diamond $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="gold$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Gold $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What js code do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the count of elements with `value="0"` and compare that with total count to `hide()` the closest element with class `points__fees`:

```js
var count = $('.points__fees__input[value="0"]').filter(function(){
  return this.value === "0";
}).get();
if($('.points__fees__input[value]').length == count.length)
  $('.points__fees__input[value="0"]').closest('.points__fees').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="points__fees">
    <div class="points__fees__label">Fees / Charges</div>
    <div class="points__fees__value">
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="star$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Star $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="diamond$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Diamond $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="gold$">
            <span class="points__fees__text">0</span> Gold $
            <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is only executed once, right? Without an event  your function is either never executed or maybe at the wrong time, or am I missing something :o

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the change event to your input fields and check their values:

```
$(".points__fees__input").bind("change", function() {        // bind change event to all input fields
    var count = 0;
    $(".points__fees__input").each(function() {                // iterate over all 3 input fields
        ((this.val() == 0) ? count += 1 : return false);       // if current value is 0, count++, otherwise stop .each()
    });
    if (count == 3) {
        $(".points__fees").hide();                           // hide if all are 0
    }    
});
```

Feel free to ask for an explanation :)

Comment: I have some comments in my answer, if that isn't enough, I will edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Just noticed [Manum's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702228/4665) answer.** This is very similar, just a little more streamlined.

Add the following to your existing JavaScript method:

```
$(".points__fees").toggle($(".points__fees input[type='hidden']").filter(function(){return this.value !== '0'}).length !== 0);
```

The `filter` method returns all elements in the target div who have a value of not 0. Visibility is then set using `toggle` based if more than 0 elements are returned from the `filter`.

**Example**:

```js
//This is emultating whatever you have now
$("#test").on("input", function() {
  //This simulates your existing value updates
  $(".points__fees input[type='hidden']").val($(this).val());
  $(".points__fees__text").html($(this).val());

  //This performs the hide/show

  /* Original  Compact Version  */
  $(".points__fees").toggle($(".points__fees input[type='hidden']").filter(function() {
    return this.value !== '0'
  }).length !== 0);

  /*This is the expanded Version of the above to illustrate the concepts
  var nonZeroFields = $(".points__fees input[type='hidden']").filter(function(){      
      return this.value !== '0'});  
  
  var showDiv = nonZeroFields.length !== 0;
  console.log(showDiv);  
  
  $(".points__fees").toggle(showDiv);
  */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>This is replicated in all fields:</label> <input type="text" id="test" />
</div>

<div class="points__fees">
  <div class="points__fees__label">Fees / Charges</div>
  <div class="points__fees__value">
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="star$">
      <span class="points__fees__text">?</span> Star $
      <input class="points__fees__input" value="?" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="diamond$">
      <span class="points__fees__text">?</span> Diamond $
      <input class="points__fees__input" value="?" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="gold$">
      <span class="points__fees__text">?</span> Gold $
      <input class="points__fees__input" value="?" type="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** this will fail if there is more than one `<div class="points__fees">`

Comment: Does this work with the op's requirements of a dynamic page? I don't see any binding or something like that, so what triggers the function?

Comment: @StephanT., it works with a dynamic page. As I mentioned in the answer, there is one line to add to their existing method. The OP mentions that the fields are dynamically updated by JavaScript, the one line just needs to be added there, preferably towards the end, though it is hard to tell without seeing the relevant original script.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script >
        function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML == 0 && document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML ==0 && document.getElementById("span3").innerHTML ==0) {
                document.getElementById("fee").hidden = true;

            }
        }
        
 </script>
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51702705/edit#
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
<script >
        function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML == 0 && document.getElementById("span2").innerHTML ==0 && document.getElementById("span3").innerHTML ==0) {
                document.getElementById("fee").hidden = true;

            }
        }
        
 </script>
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51702705/edit#
```

```
<div>
    <div class="points__fees" id="fee">
<div class="points__fees__label">Fees / Charges</div>
<div class="points__fees__value">
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="star$">
        <span class="points__fees__text" id="span1">0</span> Star $
        <input class="points__fees__input" id="input0" value="0"  type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="diamond$">
        <span class="points__fees__text" id="span2">0</span> Diamond $
        <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="points__fees__value__item" data-type="gold$">
        <span class="points__fees__text" id="span3">0</span> Gold $
        <input class="points__fees__input" value="0" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</div>
```